# Scanf skips userinput after entering a Char

Tags: c

I have a piece of code which just asks for user input and keeps prompting user for input if the user entered 0 or less.

```
float n;

do {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &n);
} while (n <= 0);
```

but when the user enters a Char it keeps executing printf() forever without prompting or waiting for user inputs.

I've used visual studio debuger with breakpoints and found that scanf() is executed without the user pressing any keys so i have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: As per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019 ,  `scanf_s` requires a buffer size. Try changing to `scanf_s("%f", &n,1);`

Comment: I just did that but same result unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to check the `scanf` return value, as good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may or may not know, `scanf_s()` returns the number of items that were successfuly converted and assigned to variables.  However, when no items are converted and assigned successfully, it returns 0.

In your case, `scanf_s()` expects a float.  So, when a `char` is entered instead, it doesn't match the conversion specifier and fails.  As a result, `scanf_s()` returns 0.

In addition, the character isn't consumed and remains in the input buffer.  So `scanf_s()` will continue to fail on that same character and loop infinitely.

**Solution**

1) Check the return value of `scanf_s()` for a failure.

2) Consume any unread characters when there's a failure.

**Suggestions**

1) Initialize your variable `n`, since it will be evaluated even when scanf_s() fails.

2) Since you want the user to enter a number greater than 0, state it specifically when prompting for one.

**Code**

```
float n = 0; /* initialize the variable */

do {
    printf("Enter a number greater than 0: ");
    if (scanf_s("%f", &n, 1) != 1)
        while (getchar() != '\n'); /* consume any unread characters */
} while (n <= 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm. I'm new to C so i had no idea about `scanf_s()` return value.  I have one more question , how `while (getchar() != '\n');` consumes unread characters? what happens if the condition evaluated to true or false?

Comment: getchar() reads a character from standard input.  So, in this case, after scanf_s() fails, getchar() reads the character that remained in the input buffer.  Since it's not '\n', the inner while expression evaluates to true, and so getchar() gets another character.  So it will continue to get more characters, if any exist, until it gets '\n', in which case the inner while expression evaluates to false, and the inner while loop is exited.